# My CSS only applied to a single page instead of all pages CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, responsive-design

I am creating a simple website using the Codeigniter Framework. I have also downloaded a responsive HTML5 template. The problem is that the CSS is only applied to the base URL of the site. But when I visit other pages the CSS is not applied. See the screenshots below.

**Controller->Pages.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
         if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/index.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('index');
                $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    function about()
    {
         if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/about.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('index');
                $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**View->Header.php**

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Official Website of Barangay Canlubang</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/init.js"></script>
  <noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/skel-noscript.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style-desktop.css" />
  </noscript>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
 </head>
```

The `index.php` and `about.php` in the View contains only HTML tags that show the content.

Comment: Have you set your base url in config.php or did you leave it blank? In codeigniter 3 if you leave it blank links may not work

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes. I set my base url in config.php. I set it to the domain name i am using

Comment: Can you edit your question by clicking on the edit button below tags with your header view and also the controller.

Comment: Have you set URL helper in autoload. Can you show me your code what you have written in view.

Comment: @Jitendra yep. I have set my URL helper in autoload.php. I will post my view.

Comment: You have added css in noscript tags, this will run when your browser javascript disable. Remove noscript tags and run.

Comment: Side note: `APPPATH.'/views/index.php'` should be `APPPATH.'views/index.php'` since `APPPATH` is ending with slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have `type="text/css"` and also remove `<noscript>` `<noscript>`

```
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/skel-noscript.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style-desktop.css" />
</noscript>
```

Change to

```
<head>
// Meta
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

// Title
<title>Official Website of Barangay Canlubang</title>

// CSS
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/skel-noscript.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style-desktop.css" />

// Scripts
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/init.js"></script>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The CSS is now applied in all pages. But after removing the noscript tag, it's not non responsive design. unlike before with noscrirpt tag, when you tried to resize the window, the site turned to mobile-friendly site.

Comment: Many thanks, just solved same issue by including the base url in the css sheet path definition

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, your CSS links are incorrect on other pages. When you are on your home page, having the CSS linked to css/something.css works, but when you go onto your other pages, it's like going into another folder. So, you need your links to go back one directory.

Instead of having css/something.css for your stylesheet, have ../css/something.css

What the ../ does is have it go back one directory before going into the CSS directory. If any more clarification is needed, please reply. Thank you! :)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/something.css" />
```

**Update 1:**
You may have been misinterpreting what the other person and I were saying.

On your home page, you are in your home directory, so the code you have for the home page would work because the CSS folder is in the same directory as your index page.

HOWEVER, when you go to another of your pages, you are going into a subdirectory of the directory that your home page is in, so the CSS folder is in the folder outside of that.

ANALOGY:

Let's say that I am on Windows, and I am in the C:\ Drive. Inside the C:\ drive, I have the following:

A folder called CSS
A folder called about
A file called index.html

So, whenever I go to this directory, it always shows up as the index.html. The index.html file is in the same directory as the CSS folder. So, linking to CSS/something.css makes sense.

Now, I am going to go to the about page. I do this by going into the about folder. However, when I try to link to the CSS folder, it's not there because it was in the folder just before the about folder.

Does this mean that you have to have a CSS folder in each of the folders that your pages are in? No! All you have to do is add this to the beginning of your link: ../

You may be asking yourself, how does adding ../ before the folder help? What ../ does is that it checks for the CSS folder in the PREVIOUS directory.

I hope that clears things up! :)

(Also, yes, I have gone into your web pages and have tried modifying the HTML to see if it works. It works once you add these changes for all of your CSS files in the pages that are not your home page.)

Comment: I am already using base_url helper of the codeigniter so that I can provide the exact path of the .css files on my directory. I have tried what you recommended earlier but the effect the same. the base url (http://barangayxyz.net23.net) is applying the css but the about page (http://barangayxyz.net23.net/pages/about) still does not. even (http://barangayxyz.net23.net/pages/index does not apply the css which basically the as the base url.

Comment: I went to the web pages you took pictures of. I added the ../ to the url in order to get it to work. I made sure this works, and it does when you add ../

Comment: You do not need to remove any noscript tags.

Comment: And you don't need to have <?php echo base_url();?> because it is not working the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?PHP echo base_url();?>css/something.css" />` should solve your problem, this way it always include CSS on on every page.

Comment: I am already using base_url helper of the codeigniter so that I can provide the exact path of the .css files on my directory. I have tried what you recommended earlier but the effect was the same. the base url (barangayxyz.net23.net) is applying the css but the about page (barangayxyz.net23.net/pages/about) still does not. even (barangayxyz.net23.net/pages/index does not apply the css which basically the same as the base url.

Answer (score 0):

one thing which is missing from all the answers is, in your html code you have to match all the classes created in that page (on which css is being displayed i.e. base URL of the site) copy all the classes declared in base url and paste them along with elements on subsequent pages.